# How should I deal with invalid input to an object constructor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, class, exception, throw

I'm trying to get my head around OOP in Javascript (I've never really used OOP in any other language either, so this is my first experience of it). I've written a class that requires an input for the constructor, but the constructor only only works with a specifically formatted string.

I have a regex that I can use to check the input against, but I don't know what I am supposed to do if it doesn't match (or if there is no input at all). Should I throw an exception of some sort? If so, how do I go about that?

Comment: Who is supposed to construct these object, where comes that string from?

Comment: @Bergi The string comes from what a user types in a box on a web page.

Comment: And which functionality builds object from the string? What do the objects do when constructed?

Comment: The object is contructed with an encrypted string, then attempts to decrypts it and holds other details about it (length, key, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript constructors (functions called with the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)) always need to return an object, you can't return `false`, `null` or similiar like when invoked normal. So, you have two options:

- throw an exception from it. You can do so with every javascript value in a [`throw` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw). Then, catch them outside the construction with a [`try` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)
- Return a usual object, but with the internal values set to a `invalid` pointer. The `Date` constructor does that for instance, getting attributes then results in `NaN`s.

Additionally (especially when using exceptions) you might provide an extra validation function (which returns boolean) as a static property on the constructor, so you can use that even before constructing an object. Example:

```
function Decryption(str) {
    if (! Decryption.test(str))
        throw new SyntaxError("invalid encryption");
    this.result = decrypt(str);
}
Decryption.test = function(str) {
    return /MyCoolRegExp/.test(str);
};
```

Comment: Ooh, I like that validation function. Could I make that a method of my object, or would that not work because the object won't exist yet?

Comment: The `test` function is no method of the `Decryption` instances, but a property on the constructor function [object].

Comment: I'm not sure I follow that. I think I'll have to read up more on the difference between a method and a property. I thought a method was just an object property that happened to be a function...

Comment: Yes, that's right. Only, a *method* does something with the object it is called on, the `test` *function* is "just namespaced" on the "class" object. The `getLength()` "method" I just added in the above example (which is prototypical inherited by all `Decryption` objects) uses the `result` property of the instance

Answer (score 6):

In JavaScript, throwing exceptions is not what you want to do. An exception sould only occur exceptionally (duh...). This is in contrast to Java, where Exceptions are used all over the place for communication. The reason for this difference is that exception handling is awfully slow in JS.

So you may very well equip your constructor with a `throw`, but that is not supposed to be caught in production. You'd rather check validity first, outside the constructor.

Do:

```
if (validRE.test(input)) {
    foo = new MyObject(input);
} else {
    // show message to the user
}
```

Don't:

```
try {
    foo = new MyObject(input);
} catch (ex) {
    // show message to the user
}
```

Comment: I'm all for validating before calling the contructor, but shouldn't I put the check in my contructor too? Otherwise it won't be very robust.

Comment: Yes, you may use both. It depends on whether or not you're planning on re-using/publishing your object. If you just use it on one website, I wouldn't worry about double-checking. Writing scripts for websites is always a trade-off between code size, speed and maintainablilty.

Comment: Just to make this clear: In my opinion, `throw` is without a doubt useful for debugging, but should be circumvented where possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to throw an exception, you can do like this:

```
throw new Error("Illegal construction string.");
```

(The `Error` object isn't mandatory, i.e. you can throw a plain string, but it will make the error message show up nicely if you handle the `onerror` event.)

As you are going to use user input, you whould probably validate the string before calling the constructor, and give the user a friendlier message than the result of an exception. You can of course still have the validation in the constructor to make sure that nothing sneaks by.

Comment: Are you saying that it is normal practice in OOP to throw an error when a contructor input is missing or invalid?

Comment: @Grezzo: Yes, if the constructor can't initialise the object properly, an exception is the only well behaving way of keeping the object from being completed.

Answer (score 1):

There's generally two ways you can go about this: either throw an exception, or return some value that indicates failure (like `undefined`). In JavaScript, I tend to lean more towards the latter, more forgiving approach.

I also find that the second approach more closely mimics a lot of JavaScript itself. For example, in Python, if you try to access a nonexistent attribute on an object, it'll throw an exception.

```
>>> foo = 0
>>> foo.idontexist
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'idontexist'
```

Whereas in JavaScript, it just returns `undefined`.

```
> var foo = 0;
> foo.idontexist
undefined
```

Many functions and objects work this way as well. For example, `Date` returns an `Invalid Date` object when passed an incorrect date string, instead of throwing an exception.

```
> var foo = new Date('thisisnotadate');
> foo
Invalid Date
```

Comment: I like the idea of returning an invalid object. Is it possible to do this with custom classes. For example my class is called person, can I return an Invalid Person object?

Comment: Honestly, I don't like the idea of invalid objects. Think about it: what are you gonna do with such an object? I suppose that `Invalid Date` is some legacy stuff from the early days of JS, where certain weird concepts were copied from Java. Also note that you cannot return `undefined` from a constructor. The `return` statement will be ignored.

Comment: Honestly, I don't like using the `new` construct directly anyway. I usually opt for factory-like functions that create objects on the fly, with fine-grained control.